# Report of all indexed PDFs with URL and Title

Tags: google-search-appliance

I have a GSA indexing around 15,000 documents. After using the GSA on our main website for sometime, we have realized a large amount of our PDFs are named incorrectly.

In order to correct the error we would like to obtain a list from the GSA of all PDFs, with their URL, and their title in search results.

Is such a report possible to pull from the GSA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export all URLs from the GSA and then use a text editor (or spreadsheet application) to view them.  If you have a large # of URLs then you might need to open first in a plain text editor and pull out only the lines with PDF in them.

Comment: Thanks Terry. For any other looking for a resolution the exact steps:
1. On GSA Index > Diagnostics > Export URLs
2. Generate GZIP file
3. Extract CSV from GZIP
4. Import CSV into Excel with tab delimited setting for further manipulation.

Exporting all pages from "Index Diagnostics" creates a file that stops at 10,000 pages.

Answer (score -1):

Your question included title and neither of the answers helped.
This is not possible in the GSA but other methods are available.
The easiest method is possible if you have access to the location where the pdf's are stored.  then using Nitro pdf software it can bulk list the titles and other metadata in the pdf,  Then you can bulk change them from an xls file.
I did this years ago to 500+ pdf files and for the price it is a steal.  I do not work for Nitro nor have any affiliation.  Just needed a task done and it did it.
the only thing it can't do is rename the files.  But the GSA uses and displays the metadata title in the pdf so that is really the most important title to get right.